# Using Flex, how to make right most div overlap left div as parent div width decreases

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive

When .parent div width (or more generically the screen width) decreases, the .right div text should overlap on top of the .left div text.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  outline: 0;
}

.left {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.right {
  width: 15px;
  min-width: 15px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background-color: pink;
  z-index: 9999999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">This is some text that can and should be overlapped as width decreases</div>
  <div class="right">This Text should always overlap text to the left</div>
</div>
```

Comment: An illustration wud help understand what u want to achieve. Also you're not using the css properly.

Comment: Single Row for the left and right divs. Right div overlaps left div when the width in this row cannot support listing all text out in a single line.

Comment: Your logic requires that the right element have a specified width. They can't _both_ be randomly flexible or neither the browser nor we can know what you want. Please revise to make it clear what that should be. Also, should the text on the left wrap at all? If so, when should it overlap?

Comment: The code in the question has a set width for the right div. So that covers your first three sentences. Your question about overlap: no. I have provided the solution to my question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.left{
overflow: hidden;
}
.parent{
width:100%;
}
```

Adding an overflow property to the left div will hide the text as the right text overlaps it in combination with a parent that is 100% width. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if I understand what you want. But here is a solution as I understood the task. When the screen has a width of less then 900px, the 'right' div will be displayed on top of the 'left' div. (Added some colors to make it easier to understand where each div is)

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.left {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right {
  width: 15px;
  min-width: 15px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background-color: pink;
  z-index: 9999999999;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .parent {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">This is some text that can and should be overlapped as width decreases</div>
  <div class="right">This Text should always overlap text to the left</div>
</div>
```